# I was a dependent in 2018 but independent in 2019. Will I get the stimulus check? And When?

Tags: taxes, irs, covid-19, stimulus

Basically I filed independently on 4/13/2020 and my Mother filed on 4/16/2020. Last year I was her dependent but this year she did not claim me as a dependent. Will I get the stimulus check? I was thinking I May miss out on the check because the taxes were completed so late and my mother already got her stimulus check before she completed the 2019 taxes.

Comment: You said "she did not claim me as a dependent", but *could* she claim you as a dependent? If she *could* claim you as a dependent (i.e. she meets the conditions in the law to claim you as a dependent), you do not qualify for the stimulus payment even if she doesn't actually claim you as a dependent.

Comment: i know she said she did not claim me on hers and I did not check the box that I could be claimed as a dependent. but we do reside at the same address. How do I know if she could claim me?

Comment: See the Form 1040 instructions section called "Who Qualifies as Your Dependent"

Comment: I am sort of confused. I lived with my mom always at the same address and she does pay for me with the exception of me paying my car and insurance. I am a college student and am 19 right now. Does this mean I won't qualify for the stimulus payment? However, I did not check the I can be claimed as a dependent on my own taxes.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, the question is not *did* she claim you, but *could* she claim you for 2019? If she could claim you for 2019 then you are not eligible.

There are other rules, but usually if she pays more than 50% of your living expenses then she can claim you. You said in the comments that

> I lived with my mom always at the same address and she does pay for
>   me with the exception of me paying my car and insurance. I am a
>   college student and am 19 right now.

Assuming she pays for the mortgage/rent, utilities, food, tuition, etc. then she is probably paying more than 50%. You should have checked the box that someone could claim you, and she should have claimed you.

Either way, you are not eligible for the stimulus check, regardless of what your mother gets. You might still get a check since you incorrectly stated that no one could claim you in 2019, but the IRS prefers that returns be true and accurate. I don't think the IRS would make you pay it back, but they could flag your return for being incorrect.

You can file an amended return to fix it, and your mom might want to file an amended return as well and claim you for the tax benefits. She will not get the $500 stimulus since you are over 16, but she still gets other credits.

Comment: I think she does pay more than 50% im not sure. Does the IRS know that though? Since I did put I cannot be claimed on my taxes.

Comment: @KellyM If she pays more than 50% then you are not eligible. Whether or not she amends her return and claims you is up to her. The IRS may never find out. But do you really want to *knowingly lie* on a federal tax form?